# Protocol Buffers Swift generation Image not found

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-buffers

This is my Contact.proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Contact {

  enum ContactType { 
    SPEAKER = 0;
    ATTENDANT = 1;
    VOLUNTEER = 2;
  }      

string first_name = 1;
  string last_name = 2; 
  string twitter_name = 3;
  string email = 4; 
  string github_link = 5; 
  ContactType type = 6;
  string imageName = 7; 
};
```

I am trying to generate its swift model by this in the directory where the proto file.

```
protoc --swift_out=. Contact.proto
```

But getting this errror:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-swift
  Reason: image not found
--swift_out: protoc-gen-swift: Plugin killed by signal 6.
```

Need help.

Comment: Hi.
Can you generate other proto files? Is seems that it isn't related to the sepcific proto file, but to the instelation of proto compiler.

Comment: Yes, i can generate python, java proto file  but the problem is specific with swift.

Comment: It seems to work for me.  When are you running into the problem?

Comment: Yeah it was running on my machine previously, i got this from this morning

Answer (score 3):

I solve the same problem. Try below.

1. delete the protoc-gen-swift
       from /usr/local/bin
2. open terminate, run    brew uninstall
       protobuf-swift
3. open terminate, run    brew install protobuf-swift

Answer (score 0):

From you questions and comments, it seems that you didn't installed the 'swift' compiler & runtime for proto.

Try this link:
https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf

Comment: swift protobuf is installed already but the outcome is the same

Comment: Did you update the xcode since you added the swift protobuf?